# Google automl train using one account and execute translations with another?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, training-data, automl

We are using the AutoML service in Google with highly trained models specific to our business.  We are looking for a solution where we can train a model in a separate "training & testing" account, then somehow use or move that model into our production account.

Is this something that is possible?  I.E. Export then import the model?  Or some function built right into the platform where we can "move" a trained model from one account to another?

The reason for this, is we have a production budget for translation service usage, but the training of the model falls outside of that cost.  We want to physically separate this activity in platform if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you can export a model o export your custom model to Cloud Storage, download the model to your server, and then use Docker to make the model available for predictions.

After that, you have to download your exported model from Cloud Storage and start the Docker container, so your model is ready to receive prediction requests in another project.

https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/model-export

Comment: The option is not available to me - even one create long after the clause: "You cannot export a model that was created before August 23, 2019.".  Plus, I'm not interested in running it local - although that would mean the per-character billing would not apply.